# How come this exists? Please corret the limit calculation

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

The problem is $
\lim _{z \rightarrow i} \frac{z^{2}+i}{z^{4}-1}
$ and the textbook's answers state that is is $-\frac{1}{2}$. How come?

My (naive) logic here being $\lim _{z \rightarrow i} \frac{z^{2}+i}{z^{4}-1}$ = $\frac{i^{2}+i}{i^{4}-1}$ =$\frac{-1+i}{(-1)^2-1}$=$\frac{i-1}{0}$. Hence $DNE$...

Comment: I expect they meant to have $z^2+1$ in the numerator.

Comment: You are right, the limit does not exist, since $(z^2 + i)/(z^4 - 1) = (z^2+i)/((z-1)(z+1)(z-i)(z+i)) = F(z)/(z-i)$ where $F$ is bounded and continuous in a neighborhood of $z = i$.

Comment: Thank you! @HansEngler for educational purpose, if you care: i'm interested in the notatation here.. By $F(z)/(z-i)$ you really mean that any $F(z)$ (why bounded and continuous?) in an open disk around $z_{0}=i$ doesn't have a limit in the situation where it's beining divided by $(z-i)$ and my function is just an instance of an $F$ in such situation? This helps a ton

Comment: @rtviii - This is shorthand for saying "there exists an $F(z)$, namely $F(z) = \frac{z^2 + i}{(z+1)(z-1)(z+i)}$ which is bounded and continuous in a neighborhood of $z = i$ such that $\frac{z^2+i}{z^4-1} = \frac{F(z)}{z-i}$". Since $F$ has a limit at $z = i$, the original fraction cannot have a limit there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the numerator is $z^2+1$. Then you have
$$\frac{z^2+1}{z^4-1}=\frac{z^2+1}{(z^2+1)(z^2-1)}=\frac{1}{z^2-1} \quad \text{so} \quad \lim_{z \rightarrow i} \frac{z^2+1}{z^4-1} = \frac{1}{i^2-1}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Great downvote ! Any reason ?

Comment: Well this makes sense too.